# How do I add a checkbox column to a DataGrid in Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm looking for a way to add a checkbox in the first column of a datagrid, so that rows can be ticked or unticked / included or excluded.

The DataGrid in Compact Framework 3.5 (developing for Windows CE 6.0) doesn't seem to include a checkbox column, like the DataGridView control does (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn).

Is there some way of simulating a checkbox column, maybe by painting a graphic into the cells, or somehow inserting an actual checkbox into the cells?

I'm ideally looking for a solution written in VB.Net.

Comment: I've tried creating my own class that inherits from DataGridTextboxColumn and then overriding the OnPaint method to draw an image of a Textbox, but I couldn't get the column to show up at all.  The only sign that anything had changed was artifacting when I scrolled left and right, which showed vertical black lines in the area I expected to see the CheckBox.

Comment: If the column is not showing up you may have not set the MappingName property on the column correctly. The DataGrid hides all non-bound columns.